# How to derive connection Lie algebra valued one-form on the frame bundle if given the pulled back of it on the physical space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I am following [this YouTube lecture by Schuller](https://youtu.be/C93KzJ7-Es4?t=5417) where he finds the appropriate formalism for the quantum mechanics in the physical curved space.

Everything makes sense to me but at the very end I see that we find the pull backed connection one-form on the base manifold.

He says to the end of the lecture that later on we will see how we can find the connection one-form on the total space, the principal bundle, i.e., the frame bundle, level.

This is not shown, however, in the next video.

I wonder how can we calculate the connection one-form on the total space when we only have information about the pulled back of this form on the base manfiold through a section map?

If we have a tangent vector on the base manifold clearly we can push it forward via the section map. But how about when we have defined a form, as we cannot push it forward from the base manifold to the total space via the section map.

Is the following a good way to illustrate in the case of a flat base space how to derive the connection one-form on the total space from the given pulled-back connection one-form on the base manifold?

Consider the trivial bundle $\mathbb{R}^2 \times G \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where $G$ is a Lie group, and let $E$ denote the principal G-bundle with fiber $G$. We can think of $E$ as the bundle whose fiber over each point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just $G$.

Suppose we have a connection one-form $\widetilde \omega$ on the base manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$ that takes values in the Lie algebra of $G$. This connection one-form is given by a one-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose values are elements of the Lie algebra of $G$ at each point.

Now suppose we have a section $s:\mathbb{R}^2 \to E$ of the principal $G$-bundle $E$. We can think of $s$ as a map that assigns to each point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ an element of $G$. We can also think of $s$ as a map that takes a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and "lifts" it to a point in $E$ by taking the point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and mapping it to the point in the fiber over that point determined by $s$.

To derive the connection one-form on the total space, we want to "lift" the pulled-back connection one-form on the base manifold to $E$. We can do this as follows:

1. Given a point $p \in E$, we can use the section map $s$ to identify the point $q=s^{-1}(p)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
2. We can then evaluate the pulled-back connection one-form $\widetilde{\omega} = s^* \omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ at the point $q$. Since $\widetilde{\omega}$ takes values in the Lie algebra of $G$, this evaluation gives us an element of the Lie algebra of $G$.
3. ** We can then "lift" this element to a Lie algebra-valued one-form on $E$ by extending it trivially in the direction transverse to the fiber. Specifically, for any vector $v$ tangent to $E$ at $p$, we can define the value of the lifted connection one-form at $p$ in the direction of $v$ to be the element of the Lie algebra of $G$ we obtained in step 2.**

By repeating this process for all points in $E$, we obtain a connection one-form on $E$ that reduces to $\omega$ when restricted to any fiber of $E$. This connection one-form satisfies all the conditions required of a connection and can be used to define parallel transport and curvature on $E$.

Comment: Which minutes? Where does Schuller introduce a group $G$?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_connection and Contemporary Geometry: Method and Applications Part 2 Doubrovin, Novikov, Fomenko, Chapter 25

Comment: @Qmechanic at minute 34, the group on the framde bundle is GL(d, R).

Comment: You should probably change the title; as the question stands (v3) it is fundamentally about diff geo and the "quantum mechanics in curved physical space" bit only really distracts from that

Comment: @NiharKarve good suggestion now updated